# How to insert json to the elasticsearch field?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin, sense

I want to index document that include json in one field. I used folloeing code.

```
JSONOBject myjson=new JSONObject(myJSONstring);
IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
            .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                    .field("jsondata",myjson )
                    .field("postDate", "date")
                    .field("message", "trying out Elasticsearch")
                    .endObject()
            )
            .get();
```

this document successfully added. when I try to query data ,myjson get as string.But I want to query inside the myjson also. can anyone help me. Thank you.

query using kibana sense,

```
 POST /twitter/tweet/_search
{
 "query": {
   "match": {
    "jsondata.amount": 0
 }
}
}
```

this gives null,

```
{
 "took": 14,
 "timed_out": false,
 "_shards": {
  "total": 5,
  "successful": 5,
  "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 0,
"max_score": null,
 "hits": []
}
}
```

Comment: "jsondata": "{\"amount\":0,\"txTime\":1456746171132,\"description\":null,\"withdrawBlock\":0}" this is the output of jsondata

Comment: Paste the mapping of `twitter`

Comment: What have you already tried ? You can access a specific sub-field by using ```jsondata.description```